# How to hide grey bar visible on iOS for custom keyboard

Tags: react-native, custom-keyboard

I have made a custom keyboard for my app that is set as visible on `onFocus` of `TextInput`. But the problem is that on iPad a grey line appears when the input is focused. 
Also I have set the Predictive to false in settings for keyboard too.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6Pl.jpg) is the screenshot of my application.

https://github.com/iamrohitagg/react-native-keyboard-android-ios is the link to my custom keyboard implementation.